# What is wrong with my Ubuntu download?

Tags: bootloader

I'm stuck at this place :

> "grub-install/dev/sda"

Its saying that the bootloader is not downloaded. What should i do?

Comment: what is installation medium ? regular cd, netinstall cd or usb stick ?

Comment: There must be a space between install and the slash. Did you check in synaptics Download manager if grub is instelled (normally always)?

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to recover boot loader then follow this link
http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/how-to-recover-grub2-linux.html